# JQuery passing list variables to another function

Tags: jquery, list, variables, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working on a YouTube web application that allows the user to use a sortable list to add links using an input field. Once the url passes a match function to check the url structure, the video ID is grabbed and placed in an Array under it's own index.

```
var _videoList = new Array();

if (matchesReg)
    {
    var container = document.getElementById('sortable');
    var _videoId; 
    //grab the video ID from the URL
    _videoId = _videoUrl.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");
    //place the Videoid in an array
    _videoList[_videoList.length] = _videoId;
    var new_element = document.createElement('li');
    //set the id of the li element to match it's position in the array
    new_element.id = _videoList.length;
    new_element.innerHTML = _videoUrl;
    container.insertBefore(new_element, container.firstChild);
    //diplay the vaild link message
    document.getElementById('msg').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Video URL added!";
    // Clean input field
    document.getElementById('newVideo').value="";
    } else {
    //failed to pass the regex test, diplay error
    document.getElementById('msg').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Error! Not a valid YouTube URL.";
    }
```

What I want to do it add a link to each new li element that will pass the video id to a cue function. How might I go about starting to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started:

```
var refId = _videoList.length;
var $new_element = $('li').attr('id', refId);
var $link = $('a')
    .attr('href', _videoUrl)
    .innerHtml(_videoUrl)
    .data('refId', refId) // add parent li's id for reference in click event
    .appendTo( $new_element )
    .bind( 'click', function(){
        cue( $link.data('refId') );
        return false; // prevent browser's default click event
    });

$new_element.appendTo( container );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_element.addEventListener('click' vid_clicked);

function vid_clicked(e){
  e=e?e:window.event;
  var id=e.target.id;
}
```

Oops. Sorry, I didn't know you wanted jQuery since there is none in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your list exists in the DOM. You do not have to pass them into the function, you merely have to select them within the process that is adding them to the queue. Something like the following should do the trick.

```
var yourFunction = function() {
    var items = $("#sortable>li");
    for (item in items) {
        // put items[item] into your queue.
    }
}
```

If you do want to pass them around, then just pass the selector in.

```
someFunction($("#sortable>li"));
```